# Auto increment column index with same lookup value (VLOOKUP)

Tags: excel, vlookup

So I got the following lookup:

=VLOOKUP(A20;Employees!A:GE;COLUMN(C:C);FALSE)

The next column should have the samen lookup value(A20), but COLUMN(D:D) as column index number. And this continues for a couple of hundred columns.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is, change this formula to `=VLOOKUP($A20;Employees!$A:$GE;COLUMN(C:C);FALSE)`
And then fill to the right. The `$` keeps the number or column letter from changing.